# Make the methods of a library not visible for external access but visible for the library

Tags: java, methods, package, visibility

I developed a library and I need that the users of that library can access only to one class ( with a few methods).

For other side I need that this class can access to all library's methods-classes.

One solution is to put all the classes in the same package and make all methods protected but I dont like having a library with different classes for different purposes. (like a class to use video and a class to parse a XML) in the same package.

Now:

com.aracem.library:
- class 1
- class 2
- class 3
- class 4
- class 5

I want something like this

com.aracem.library:
- class 1
com.aracem.library.video
- class 2 video
com.aracem.library.xml
- class 3 xml
- class 4 xml

How can I define the methods of the clas 2 , 3 , 4 (in the example) to let class 1 access to the methods but dont let the users of the library access that methods?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since java does not have yet any access control mechanism except access modifiers (private, protected, public, or nothing for package-protected access) I can suggest you the following solution.

All classes should be package-protected. To be able to call your own classes from other package create public interfaces in your packages and make your classes to implement these interfaces. The instances of classes should be created by your factory only. Put factory per package. The factory class itself is public.

Now, there is only one possibility for client code to access your classes: instantiate them using your factory. But the factory should check the access rights of caller. It is simple: `new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0]` returns you the stack trace element of your caller. Examine its package and decide whether you should go on or throw `Exception`, e.g. `SecurityException`.

There are other solutions. You can for example wrap all your classes using aspects. For example use AspectJ that performs byte code modification and inserts some code automatically. This code will check the access rights and throw exception as explained above. This solution is probably better but requires you to learn a bit about AspectJ.

Comment: What do you think about the idea of create a library with the other classes (in this case xml and video) and include it like a .jar. This idea solution the problem too, isn't it?